# Chart.js Doughnut chart inner label different than outer

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, pie-chart

I am trying to create a chart that has a different inner label compared to its 'legend'.  Chart.js shrinks when the legend is too long which pushes my chart to a very tiny size.  I took the labels and chopped them off after a certain length and that is the new label.  However I dont know how to have two separate labels, one so the Legend is the shortened version and one being the normal length.  Here is my code:

```
function truncLabel(str, maxwidth){
if(str.length > maxwidth) {
    str = str.substring(0,24)+"...";
}
return str;
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < labels2Length; i++){
        trunc_labels2[i] = formatLabel(labels2[i],20);
    }


    new Chart(document.getElementById("xxx"), {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: trunc_labels2,
        datasets: [
            {
            label: labels2,
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850","#5e5ba3","#9fe7aa","#1a5ba3","#6cba1f","#cacf4f"],
            data:data2
        }
        ]} //More code follows but isnt needed here
```

Labels2 correctly returns the full string, while trunc_labels2 correctly returns the truncated string.  Other types of charts have this feature (ie bar, line etc) but it seems doughnut doesnt?
Thank you

Comment: So you want to have labels in legend and pop-up after hover to chart part?

Comment: @SirWojtek I want the legend to be the truncated version but the hover over to be the full label.  Ie legend = thisismyreallylon...  tooltop = thisismyreallylongstring

Comment: @ℊααnd That 'shouldnt' become an issue since none of the labels will hit that length.  Mind telling me how you were able to separate the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To truncate the labels/strings - use [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method along with [**`substring()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), for instance :

```
let labels = [
   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
];
let trunc_labels = labels.map(e => e.substring(0, 12) + '...');
```

Now, to show the original labels on tooltips, use the following tooltip­*'s* label callback function :

```
callbacks: {
   label(t, d) {
      let xLabel = labels[t.index],
          yLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index];
      return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
   }
}
```

<sup>* *make sure `labels` is a global variable.*</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
let labels = [
   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
];
let trunc_labels = labels.map(e => e.substring(0, 12) + '...');

let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'doughnut',
   data: {
      labels: trunc_labels,
      datasets: [{
         data: [1, 1, 1],
         backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(0, 119, 220, 0.8)',
            'rgba(0, 119, 220, 0.6)',
            'rgba(0, 119, 220, 0.4)'
         ]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label(t, d) {
               let xLabel = labels[t.index],
                   yLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index];
               return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello i am use chart.js adn create bar chart and i am getting success. but i am facing one problem related chart so can you please help me. i have add filter in charts like month wise week wise data show in chart first time data show month wise then after change in drop down and select week wise data show then chart is create but then after i am going on chart and mouse pointer move from left to right my chart automatically change and show month wise data so i want stop this so how can do any idea?

Comment: Please don't ask questions in comment section, rather post a new question describing your problem thoroughly and what you've tried so far to solve it.

Comment: yes i am asking post please give me some hint on that post this is my post id => 45875358 so can you please help me?

Comment: @ℊααnd Greatly appreciate this answer.  Had to tweak a bunch but ended up getting it working (though the chart renders outside of its container).  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have an answer to your question. You must secify `label` callback function returning a string that should be shown inside tooltip (pop-up):

```
     options: {
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
          label: function (item, data) {
            return 'my custom label text';
          }
        }
     }
```

Here is Plunker with an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/fsQu7QNb6PnhnGhgvxR9

Comment: Thank you for this.  I gave the answer to the one above because it was more fleshed out but this example helped.